# Faster way to go through csv file in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, csv

I have million records in a file and need to do some calculations. For this i have java program and a same copy of c++ program but Java perform way faster than c++. Main reason i switched to c++ is to perform multithreading to make the program run faster. But when i compare 1 thread work between java and c++, java does the job in half the time.

I need to fix this problem. C++ suppose to go faster but it perform poorly.

Some good nice heads up will be nice so i can research and try fixing it.

Thanks

This is the class that makes objects out of the comma separated data

```
//Parser.cpp 
#include "Parser.h"
#include "PriceBar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

vector<PriceBar> Parser :: parseFile(string file){

    string STRING;
    vector<PriceBar> bars;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open (file.c_str());
    int a=0;
    string token;


while(getline(infile,STRING)) // To get you all the lines.
{
    vector<string> data;
    istringstream ss(STRING);
    while(getline(ss, token, ',')) {
                data.push_back(token);
            }
    //cout<<data[4]<<endl;

    if(!data[1].empty()){
                            //cout << "if is working" << endl;
                            double open = atof(data[1].c_str());
                            double high = atof(data[2].c_str());
                            double low = atof(data[3].c_str());
                            double close = atof(data[4].c_str());
                            bars.push_back(PriceBar(open, high, low, close));
                        }//end of if

}//end of while
infile.close();
//cout << "parser is done " << bars[2].getOpen() <<endl;
//cout << bars.size() << endl;
return bars;

}
```

Pricebar class

```
/*
 * PriceBar.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Nov 5, 2013
 *      Author: hansaka
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "PriceBar.h"

using namespace std;

PriceBar :: PriceBar(double open, double high, double low, double close){
this -> open = open;
this -> high = high;
this -> low = low;
this -> close = close;
}

double PriceBar :: getOpen() {
    return open;
}
void PriceBar :: setOpen(double open) {
    this -> open = open;
}
double PriceBar :: getHigh() {
    return high;
}
void PriceBar :: setHigh(double high) {
    this -> high = high;
}
double PriceBar :: getLow() {
    return low;
}
void PriceBar :: setLow(double low) {
    this -> low = low;
}
double PriceBar :: getClose() {
    return close;
}
void PriceBar :: setClose(double close) {
    this -> close = close;
}
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "PriceBar.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
Parser p;

//getting the counter ready
time_t tstart, tend;

//Starting the time
tstart = time(0);

vector<string> path;
path.push_back("file.csv");

for( vector<string>::const_iterator it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); ++it ){
  //    cout << *it << endl;
    vector<PriceBar> priceBars = p.parseFile(*it);
    //priceBars = p.parseFile(*it);

//      cout << "done" << endl;

    double maxHigh = 0.0;
    double maxLow = 0.0;
    double maxOpen = 0.0;
    double maxClose = 0.0;
    double maxVolume = 0.0;
    double current = 0.0;

  //     cout << "hippy " << priceBars[2].getOpen() <<endl;
   int size = priceBars.size();
 //      cout << "size = " << size << endl;


    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        current = priceBars[j].getOpen();
        if (current > maxOpen) {
            maxOpen = current;
        }
    }//end of pricebar for

    current = 0.0;
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        current = priceBars[j].getOpen();
        if (current > maxHigh) {
            maxHigh = current;
        }
    }
    current = 0.0;
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        current = priceBars[j].getOpen();
        if (current > maxLow) {
            maxLow = current;
        }
    }
    current = 0.0;
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        current = priceBars[j].getOpen();
        if (current > maxClose) {
            maxClose = current;
        }
    }

                cout << "MaxHigh =" << maxOpen << " MaxLow = " << maxHigh
                        << " MaxHigh =" << maxLow << " MaxLow = " << maxClose << endl;


}//end of it for
cout << "DONE" << endl;

//Ending the time count
tend = time(0);

cout << " It took " << difftime(tend, tstart) << " second(s).";

return 0;
}
```

I have been editing this code a lot so no much comments and there are code parts I just have commented out for my reference and i apologize for that.

Comment: Directly copying code from Java to C++ will rarely result in better performance. Allocations are generally a lot more expensive in C++ than in GCed languages. Your best bet is to try reducing those.

Comment: I suspect the running time to be dominated by IO, therefore I am not sure how multithreading could help. Anyway, do you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Did you compile with optimization turned on?

Comment: it's not C++ that doesn't perform well, it's your C++ program that doesn't. just because you translated some java code into C++ code doesn't mean you should expect better performance.

Comment: for instance why are you using a `std::vector` for `data` that only has 5 elements? why don't you use a fixed-size sequence such as `std::array` or even a C-style array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I would do:

1. Move construction of objects used during reading the file out of the loops an rather clear them. Constructing streams isn't cheap and allocating memory for vectors and strings all the time instead of reusing it isn't effective.
2. I wouldn't really store a `std::vector<std::string>` as it is sufficient to store a `std::vector<double>`, converting the individual values directly.
3. The current code doesn't check if it actually read enough entries on each line which may result in an out of bounds access for a misformatted file. If the file contains more than 5 columns it may be worth not decoding the trailing columns.
4. In `main()` I would call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`. I'd hope that it doesn't make much of a difference, though (it does improve performance of using the standard stream objects but I could imagine that it also affects file streams for a really bad IOStream implementation).
5. Since IOStreams are often implemented in headers, it is very important to enable optimizations, at least, for the translation units doing having I/O.

Here is how I would write the function:

```
std::vector<PriceBar> Parser::parseFile(std::string const& file) {
    std::vector<PriceBar> bars;
    std::ifstream         infile(file.c_str());
    std::istringstream    lin;
    std::vector<double>   columns;

    for (std::string line, topic, value; std::getline(infile, line); ) {
        lin.clear();
        lin.str(line);
        columns.clear();
        for (std::getline(lin, topic, ','); getline(ss, value, ',')) {
            columns.push_back(value.empty()? 0.0: std::atof(value.c_str()));
        }
        if (columns.size() == 4) {
            bars.push_back(PriceBar(columns[0], columns[1], columns[2], columns[3]));
        }
    }
    return bars;
}
```

I don't think dealing with multiple threads would help much. Reading a tiny file with just a million or so lines doesn't warrant the corresponding complexity.

Comment: Thanks, this is just a start. There are big codes written in java that takes about 9 days to finish processing. So i wanted them to be threaded so at least i wanna cut down the processing time half by using one node with multiple processors or either multiple nodes. All the processing depends on millions millions of records.